# How to use pointers in PL1 programming language

Tags: mainframe, pl-i

I am trying to learn the use of pointers in PL1. However below approach is not working

```
  DCL MYPTR PTR;                               
    DCL MYVAR CHAR(10) INIT('1234567890');       
    PUT SKIP(2) LIST('DISPLAY MYVAR: ',MYVAR);   
    MYPTR = ADDR(MYVAR);                             
    PUT SKIP(2) LIST('DISPLAY MYPTR: ',MYPTR);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 DISPLAY MYVAR:          1234567890               
                                                 
DISPLAY MYPTR:
```

Comment: What compiler are you using for your tests? The same code shows readable output for me with Enterprise PL/I 5.2 on z/OS. Perhaps your compiler is printing the pointer-value as binary without converting to text. Have you checked whether there are some non-displayable characters in your output?

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are variables that contain a storage address. You use them to remap a storage area with different layout. For example, assume you've got records in a single data set that have different layout, say:

```
dcl 1 RecordType1,
      2 RecType        char( 01 ),
      2 Field01        char( 10 ),
      2 Field02        char( 20 ),
      2 Number01       decimal packed( 10,2 ),
      2 Field03        char( 10 );

dcl 1 RecordType2,
      2 RecType        char( 01 ),
      2 Field01        char( 05 ),
      2 *              char( 02 ), 
      2 Number01       bin fixed( 31 ),
      2 Numner02       bin fixed( 31 ),
      2 Field02        char( 100 );
```

These declarations set aside *two distinct storage areas*, one for each type. Note that the records have different lengths. How would you read in the records, if you only know the type, and with this the length *after* having read the record? You would need to do something like:

- reading into an area long enough for the longest type,
- check the type,
- move to the structure according to the type
- process the individual fields.

This involves a lot of unnecessary data moves.

Using pointers, and the associated `based()` attribute in declarations, you can define the structures as mapping, i.e. witout underlying storage. You then use a single pointer for all mappings.

```
dcl 1 RecordType1      based( pRecord ),
      2 RecType        char( 01 ),
      2 Field01        char( 10 ),
      2 Field02        char( 20 ),
      2 Number01       decimal packed( 10,2 ),
      2 Field03        char( 10 );

dcl 1 RecordType2      based( pRecord ),
      2 *              char( 01 ),
      2 Field01        char( 05 ),
      2 *              char( 02 ), 
      2 Number01       bin fixed( 31 ),
      2 Numner02       bin fixed( 31 ),
      2 Field02        char( 100 );

dcl pRecord            prt;
dcl LongestRecord      char( 116 );

pRecord = addr( LongestRecord );
```

Now, you do something like this:

- read the record into the `LongestRecord` field,
- test the type by inspecting the type field `RecType` (assuming the type indicator is at the same position for each type).
- Access the individual files via qualified variable reference, e.g. `RecordType1.Field01`, or `RecordType2.Number02`

No more unnecessary data moves from input area to mapping area..

If you read the records from a data set, you can even avoid the first move and access the records directly in the *input buffer*; just tell the read statement to set the pointer, instead of moving the data into the `LongestRecord` field:

```
dcl fInput             external file record input;
...
read file( fInput ) set( pRecord );
```

You can now drop the declaration for the `LongestRecord` variable, and the statement setting `pRecord` to the address of that variable.

*For completeness, only*: PL/I offers another way to map a storage area with two or more different layouts: `UNION`, but this is not the question here.